# How to modify the new WordPress 4.5 link inline toolbar

Tags: plugin-development

I had my own plugin that add custom links options to the old wordpress link edition window (data attribute, nofollow etc).

The [new inline link toolbar](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2016/03/28/the-editor-in-wordpress-4-5/) introduced in WordPress 4.5 is ... not what I want! **All options need one more click**: writers are not anymore paying attention to links properties, and it's a big problem.

How to do one of the following:

- Either disable the new wordpress inline toolbar (programmatically)?
- Write code (JS or PHP) to add buttons to this toolbar?